# Sending variables to different activities

Tags: java, android

In my MainActivity, I create a variable called "pengar". I then send this variable to my second activity using putExtra on the intent. In the second activity, I edit the variable, however as I use the back button to return to my main activity, I can't use putExtra.

Comment: Many design patterns to pass the data, using intents, start the second activity with startForResult and set data in result while second activity finished. User callback onActivityResult in first activity to get back the data set in the result by the second activity. Read more on Android Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Write below code in your MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            pengar = extras.getString("key2");
        }
}
 public void nextActivity(View view) 
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key1",pengar);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Write below code in your SecondActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Bundle extras1 = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras1 != null) {
            var2 = extras1.getString("key1");
        }
    public void backButton(View view) 
{
        Intent intent2= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent2.putExtra("key2",var2);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }
}
```

Hope this helpful